# Brownian Motion Covariance: max instead of min

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

It is known that $\operatorname{Cov}(B_t,B_s)=\min(t,s)$ where $B$ is Brownian motion.
Can one think of an Ito process or integral (preferrably plain Gaussian process) $W$ such that $\operatorname{Cov}(W_t,W_s)=\max(t,s)$?

Let me ask it in another way: it is known that $k(x,y)=\min(x,y)$ is the reproducing kernel of the Cameron Martin RKHS. What is the RKHS (if any) of the kernel $k(x,y)=\max(x,y)$?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Please recall that
$$\operatorname{Cov}(B_s,B_t)=\operatorname{Cov}(sB_{1/s},tB_{1/t})$$

but I didn't manage to go further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that this has a (non-deleted) answer:

No such process can exist.  If $\operatorname{Var}(W_0) = \max(0,0) = 0$ then $W_0$ is a constant.  In particular, $W_0$ and $W_1$ are independent, so we have $\operatorname{Cov}(W_0, W_1)= 0 \ne 1= \max(0,1)$.

More generally, Cauchy-Schwarz shows that for any process with finite variance, we have $\operatorname{Cov}(X_s, X_t) \le \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_s) \operatorname{Var}(X_t)}$.  Thus the covariance function $k(s,t)$ must satisfy $k(s,t) \le \sqrt{k(s,s) k(t,t)}$.  The function $k(s,t) = \max(s,t)$ does not, so it cannot be a covariance function.

Answer (score 1):

If $0<s<t$ then
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cov}(B_t,B_s) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{cov}(B_s + (B_t-B_s),B_s) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{cov}(B_s,B_s) + \operatorname{cov}(B_t-B_s,B_s) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{var}(B_s) + 0 = s.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks! but how would you represent this backward-brownian-motion in terms of Ito process or Ito integral?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The covariance is never max(s,t).

Comment: @did : Let $C_t=B_t-B_1$.  Then for $0<s<t<1$, you've got $\operatorname{cov}(C_s,C_t) = t$, i.e. it's the maximum.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Not at all. For the reason why this example fails and why any other would fail as well, see my now deleted answer.

Comment: @did : OK, I see: it's the distance from the point where the process is fixed (in the example, $1$) and the nearest of the two indices to that point.

Answer (score 1):

The function $k:(t,s)\mapsto\max(t,s)$ is not a covariance kernel since, for example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ has a negative eigenvalue.

**Edit:** About the Edit in the question, note that
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(sB_{1/s},tB_{1/t})=st\cdot\operatorname{Cov}(B_{1/s},B_{1/t})=st\cdot\min(1/s,1/t)=\min(s,t),
$$
which is certainly not equal to $\max(s,t)$.

Comment: great observation! so we're left with the first question :) see prev answer and comment pls. In addition, please note that for $k:(t,s)\mapsto\min(t,s)$, $\begin{pmatrix}-2 & -2\\ -2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ has all eigens negative. so maybe we can talk on $max$ as a kernel when we deal with negatives

Comment: sorry, it has one neg eigenvalue (but still)

Comment: No *we are not left with the first question*. Say, are you seriously considering that a covariance matrix can have $-2$ and $-1$ as diagonal entries? Then I suggest to check the definition of these matrices.

Comment: ok, i see. so you say that no process can give a max covariance (even though for reproducing kernels, things might be slightly more generalized). so what you actually say is that there isn't a process which is time-reversed-brownian-motion (which makes sense)

Comment: No process has max(s,t) as covariance. To say that *there isn't a process which is time-reversed-brownian-motion* would be absurd, there is (and I really wonder how one can extract THAT from what I wrote).

Comment: see the first answer which seems to make sense

Comment: You really do not read what I write, do you? If you had, you would know as a fact that the last sentence of the answer you mention, does not make any sense.

Comment: i did read it very well, sorry if i'm not bright and perfect as you, please forgive me. i meant for the first answer by Michael Hardy

Comment: Could you unaccept my answer please?

Comment: why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Just do it. $ $